# Choosing database for complex survey application

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, database, nosql

My problem is that in the system I design with each question person can assess one of objects of type **A**, **B**, or **C** with for example number or some value from fixed (for this particular question) answer set. In some complex situations, even objects of type **A**, **B** and **C** can be taken as an assessment value.

To demonstrate, there are simple questions, such as:

> Please rate **A12** on the scale from 1 to 100

and complex ones, such as

> Please pick best object of type **A** for object **B42**

with answers

- A31,
- A6,
- A42.

Each of the object types - **A**, **B** and **C** cannot be generalised (at least, directly). They surely don't have any common properties and in some scenarios can be related to each other.

Answers given by people are the most crucial data in the system.

I should also mention that all other data fits perfectly into a relational database.

Normally, I prefer control I get from relational databases, but now I consider noSql solutions, as they may fit better.

So, I am asking you to help me answer these questions:

- Which database should I use - relational, noSql or some mixed solution (for example, postgresql with array/json columns)?
- If relational database is used

  - do I use sparse relations (tables) for describing questions and answers
  - or should I normalise schema, creating dozens of tables?

Comment: Hey, SO isn't great for opinion based questions, have a look at the info on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @theatlasroom I am sorry, but i disagree. I briefly looked through page you provided. My question sure is opinion-based, but I am not looking for creating dispute or having a chit-chat about databases. I am asking advise about which solution fits best and why.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a trivial case of data-modelling.

Comment: It is not completely an opinion based question but it isn't a full data modeling question either.  You should make some statistics on how much data you're going to process with this.  Unless you're going to have hundreds of hits per minute, you should just use a standard normalized relational database.

Comment: @grochmal I do not expect this system to get to high-loaded, but I sure want it to be easily expandable (as new types of objects are to be added) and easily perceived by other programmers. Fully normalised solution (that I can think of) leads me to creating dozens of tables, and the count will grow when new object types are introduced

Comment: Are you talking about [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)?